# Updating a hash value with a new one

Tags: ruby

I prompted the user to add a new rating to append the old one but the value still remains the same. What am I doing wrong here?

```
movies = { the_dark_knight: 9, mrs_doubtfire: 8.5 }
    puts "***** Welcome to the movie guide!! ***** "
    puts "***** Enter a choice! *****"
choice = gets.chomp

case choice
when "add"
    puts "Please enter the title of the movie"
title = gets.chomp
    puts "Now enter your rating for this movie!"
rating = gets.chomp
    if movies[title.to_sym] == nil
        movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    else puts "That movie already exists!"
    end


when "update"
    puts "Enter the title that you would like to update!"
updater = gets.chomp
if movies[updater.to_sym] == nil
    puts "This movie does not exist in the database!"
else puts " Ok! What is your new rating?"
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[updater] = rating.to_i
    movies
end
```

Comment: It seems as though I forgot to convert updater to a symbol here. That fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your updater is a string, while the hash is symbol accessed. replace:

`movies[updater] = rating.to_i`

with

`movies[updater.to_sym] = rating.to_i`